# Send Geolocated Tweet with Tweetsharp

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

I am trying to tweet with geolocation with tweetsharp api. I did use

`TwitterStatus status = ts.SendTweet(s,lat,lon);`

code. But status object reference is null. How can i send geolocated tweet?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't give a lot of details but I'll try to help. I suppose you have retrieved latitude and longitude and they're not null, and also that your variable `s` contains a valid status string.

Then, the most probable cause of the error is the Twitter API. Check the response with `ts.Response`, either in the debug or printing `ts.Response.StatusCode` and `ts.Response.Response`.

Hope this may help you.